# Ignore nanoseconds in createFromFormat

Tags: php, datetime-format

I'm trying to create a DateTime from the following string:

> 2012-02-16 00:45:54.441899

I tried with this format, without success:

> Y-m-d H:i:s.*

What can I do? I don't care about the part after the dot.

Comment: Technically, six digits (441899) are only micro seconds, not nano seconds. Micro seconds was added to PHP 5.2.2. The real trouble starts when you have to deal with actual nano seconds because PHP doesn't support it yet.

Comment: Oh right my bad, micro seconds indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot the microsecond part of the format:

```
$s = '2012-02-16 00:45:54.441899';
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', $s);//format looks like your string
echo $d->format('Ymd');//output format can be whatever you like
```

Comment: I did not forget it, I tried to use a star instead, because these are nanoseconds, not microseconds

Comment: since it's a 6 digit number that will always be ignored, it doesn't really matter if they ns, µs or woozlebats. The worst that can ever happen is that your seconds will be rounded incorrectly.

Comment: I don't understand why they are ignored, but it seems your right. I'll edit your answer with an example in a few seconds.

Comment: @greg0ire: if you're concerned about rounding try this format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s|.u' which will zero the u part

Comment: seems to work great! thanks! You should put that in your answer. Or not. Not putting the | does the same. Do you understand why?